# Azure traffic manager performance balancing with nested profiles with different data centers

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

How does the 'performance' option in azure traffic manager work with child profiles, when the child profiles contain data centers in different sub-regions?

I understand the performance option sends traffic to the nearest data center which makes sense, but what about when it's choosing between nested-profiles, as those profiles could contain data centers anywhere.

SO, if I create several nested profiles 'europe-zone', 'us-zone', 'asia-zone' each with a number of different data centers below it how will the traffic be routed exactly / exactly how will it select a zone.

1. europe-zone

   1.1 north-europe

   1.2 west-europe
2. us-zone

   2.1 east-us

   2.2 west-us

   2.3 central-us
3. asia-zone

   3.1 japan

   3.2 east-asia

I have not find any detailed info on this scenario, the examples given, for example this one http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/29/new-azure-traffic-manager-nested-profiles/ don't explain the behaviour.

Remember I could have had profiles like

1. profile 1

   1.1 japan

   1.2 west-us
2. profile 2

   2.1 japan

   2.2 west-us

Do how would it select then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question.  You're right that Traffic Manager can't easily infer the 'location' of a child profile since it may contain a mixture of endpoints.  To resolve this, Traffic Manager requires you to specify the location of each child profile directly.

To do this via PowerShell, use the '-location' parameter of Add-AzureTrafficManagerEndpoint when adding the child profile to the parent profile.

The location must be specified in this way for any endpoints of type 'Any' (used for external services) or endpoints of type 'TrafficManager' (used for nested Traffic Manager profiles), when the 'Performance' traffic-routing method is used.